# Push files from jenkins workspace to remote git repository

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkins job runs Sahi Automation tests. I use GitLab as the SCM Repository. In the process it creates some artifacts(text files). I want to push the created files (in the workspace) to the Git Repository. I tried using Git Publisher, but it is not as I want. How can I push the files from jenkins workspace to git repository.
I tried using Git Publisher, but it is not working

Answer (score -1):

what is the error that you are getting.
Usually , it works fine if you add git publisher plugin and add 
shell/batch commands in jenkins
git commit -m "xyz"
git push <> Head : branchname

Also , did you try verifying the credentials you set ! 
check that in your sourcecode tab in jenkins.

Cheers.
AJ

Comment: Hi, do we need both?, the git bash commands in shell and the git publisher configuration? I think the issue is the files are created in jenkins workspace and not in the local git repository. The publisher is not considering the files from workspace to push them in repo

Comment: Hello Advait , I f I understand correctly, you have added a post-build step action to publish result/test file to push changes. Usually Git publisher is good for merge results, tags, and/or branches to remote repositories.

Comment: Try with Git Push coomand as a shell/ batch command. It should work. I really want to see what the log says. And if possible share what/how did you configure in Git Publish exactly? 
good luck